# SQL query in outlook macro

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to pull some information from out helpdesk system into the subject line of an email. the helpdesk system is MSSQL based

My goal is to have a form with a multi column ComboBox that inserts the results of the SQL query into a multi column combobox respectively.

I was planning to use the selected value in the combo box to insert into the subject line of an email, with some text manipulation. but I have not get that far yet :)

This code gives me the query in the combobox however the data is in two separate rows, where I would like them in the same row

can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub userform_initialize()
UserForm1.ComboBox1.ColumnCount = 2
On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
cnn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=sqlserver;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=databasename;" & _
              "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
rst.Open "Select field1, field2 from table", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
rst.MoveFirst

With UserForm1.ComboBox1
    .Clear
    Do
       .AddItem rst.Fields(0)
        .AddItem rst.Fields(1)
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit
```

Comment: try this in your select statement - `Select field1 + ' ' + field2 from table`  I'm no expert at outlook macros, but I think this should work...If this does work, let me know, and I'll expand upon this comment some and make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are twice adding an item to the combobox (one for each field), so of course you get separate rows. If you first put the results in a two dimensional array (arr(rowcount, 1) ) and then set the items property of the combobox to the array it should have two columns (you still may have to set the properties of the combobox to show both columns though)

Comment: Dorry for the delay that work here is the modified code 
          
         `Do
           combinedlist(0) = rst.Fields(0)
           combinedlist(1) = rst.Fields(1)
            rst.MoveNext
     With UserForm1.ComboBox1
        .ColumnCount = 2
        .AddItem "[[WO#" & combinedlist(0) & "]]" & " - " & combinedlist(1)
        
     End With
     Loop Until rst.EOF`